# The current path, login/, didn’t match any of these

Tags: python, django, path, django-urls

I have one app on my project which named "bookstore".

http://127.0.0.1:8000/login/ is rising an error that the current path, login/, didn't match any of these.

In addition that the urls were working properly the last time I was working on my project and I didn't do any changes to my code.

I'm using Django version 3.2.2

**The bookstore/urls.py file**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    path('', views.home),
    path('login/', views.login),
    path('about/', views.about)

]
```

**The main urls.py file**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('bookstore.urls'))
]
```

**The views.py file**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, "bookstore/dashboard.html")

def login(request):
    return render(request, "bookstore/login.html")

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("About Us")
```

**The settings.py file**

```
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bookstore'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'blog.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'blog.wsgi.application'
```

Comment: Does index work, so just `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`?

Comment: @TomWojcik It shows me the index page of Django not the home page I designed.

Comment: @TomWojcik I reviewed the path of my folder and noticed that the project folder is duplicated in different paths and the error happens in the wrong project. So sorry for the inconvenience, Tom and thanks for your concern.